# Fourier coefficients of a "shifted" periodic function

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function. Also, assume $x\in\mathbb{R}$. My question is, how could I evaluate
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t-x)e^{-int}dt$$
in terms of the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of $f$, i.e.,
$$\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)e^{-int}dt?$$
Any of your help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t-x) e^{-int} dt = e^{-inx} \int_{-\pi+x}^{\pi+x} f(t) e^{-int} dt = e^{-inx} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int} dt$$ where in the last equality we have used the periodicity of the integrand.

Comment: Thanks so much! But I am still unclear about the first equality. Could you please explain?

Comment: Does it hold because of the change of variables?

Comment: Yes, I made the change of variables $t \to t+x$.